# Insert multiple rows with onConflict clause in partitioned table in Postgres 10

Tags: postgresql, partitioning, upsert, postgresql-10

I have a statement like the following in Postgres 10:

```
INSERT INTO my_table(A, B)
       VALUES (val_A1, val_B1),
              ...
              (val_A99, val_B99)
       ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;
```

Which was working well, but later I partitioned my table and then this statement started to fail:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: 
ON CONFLICT clause is not supported with partitioned tables
```

As Postgres 10 [doesn't support ON CONFLICT clauses on partitioned tables](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/ddl-partitioning.html):

> Using the ON CONFLICT clause with partitioned tables will cause an error, because unique or exclusion constraints can only be created on individual partitions. There is no support for enforcing uniqueness (or an exclusion constraint) across an entire partitioning hierarchy.

If I were inserting a single row I could attempt the INSERT and control the error with a try-catch if the record was already there.

But being that I'm inserting multiple values, what alternatives do I have besides this one:

```
INSERT INTO my_table
       SELECT T.A, T.B
       FROM (VALUES(val_A1, val_B1), 
                   ...,
                   (val_A99, val_B99)) AS T(A, B),
       WHERE NOT EXISTS (
           SELECT 1 FROM my_table AS T2
                    WHERE T2.A = T.A
                      AND T2.B = T.B
       );
```

Answer (score 1):

Your best option is to upgrade to PostgreSQL v11, where this will work.

PostgreSQL v11 supports `PRIMARY KEY` and `UNIQUE` constraints on partitioned tables (if the partition key is part of the index), and that is a requisite for `INSERT ... ON CONFLICT`.

Comment: I'm using Postgres in RDS, where only up to version 10.6 is currently supported. I saw they are working on supporting version 11, but there is still no release date from their part.

Comment: The best option then is to use [the old way](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-UPSERT-EXAMPLE).